# Encountering error while using Enter key, space bar, and backspace in wxpython wx.TextCtrl

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets, wx.textctrl

alphabet keys(a-z) numeric keys(0-9) are mapped to unicode values, in a text editor which uses the wx.TextCtrl.

The line in which error encounters is given below,

```
self.statusbar.SetStatusText(engine.roman2mal(self.word.decode('utf-8')),0)
```

The error message is as given below,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\EZHUTHANI_WIN\ezhuthani\beditor.py", line 498, in PreviewConv
    self.statusbar.SetStatusText(engine.roman2mal(self.word.decode('utf-8')),0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to map these keys(Enter, Space Bar, Backspace)? the other keys are mapped as given below,

```
keymap = {}
keymap['a'] = u'\u0D05';
keymap['A'] = u'\u0D06';
```

Comment: Can I have the code ?

Comment: the code is added in the last edit...

Comment: This has nothing to do with wxWidgets, the error happens in `codecs.utf_8_decode` as the callback clearly shows, so your `word` doesn't contain a valid UTF-8 string.

Comment: this error occurs only on the keystrokes of backspace, space bar and enter key

Comment: Do you have any function uses .decode? If yes post the code

Comment: self.statusbar.SetStatusText(engine.roman2mal(self.word.decode('utf-8')),0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.statusbar.SetStatusText(engine.roman2mal(self.word.decode('utf-8')),0)
```

You have to remove .decode function  then the code will look like

```
 self.statusbar.SetStatusText(engine.roman2mal(self.word),0)
```

Comment: solved the issue... the code had the decode?encode functions used in multiple places. it didn't actually had to do that since python can print the unicode characters without it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you to achieve, but it sounds like you want to be using

```
wx.WXK_BACK
wx.WXK_ESCAPE
wx.WXK_RETURN
...
```

perhaps

```
keymap = {}
keymap[wx.WXK_ESCAPE] = u'<ESCAPE>'
...
```